# ¿Por qué mis archivos .css y .js no son reconocidos al desplegar una aplicación en App Engine de Google Cloud?

Tags: php, symfony, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

He logrado desplegar exitosamente la aplicación de prueba de Symfony en Google App Engine. Pero cuando navego a la URL de la aplicación el contenido se carga sin formato y sin estilo. Al revisar la consola del navegador tengo varios errores 404 relativos a los archivos `.css` y `.js`.

Dejo aquí los log de error:

```
2022-11-01 13:19:15 default[20221101t141557]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302
2022-11-01 13:19:15 default[20221101t141557]  nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /tmp/google-config/nginx.conf:3
2022-11-01 13:19:18 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /es HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-01 13:19:19 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/runtime.725dd7e0.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 13:19:19 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/823.168b723b.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 13:19:19 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/31.46aa6824.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 13:19:19 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/app.17316efd.css HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 13:19:19 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/95.22c66ae4.css HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 13:19:19 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/app.c5bd2611.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 13:19:19 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/95.1ed6b32f.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 13:19:19 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/755.5a8586e9.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 13:19:26 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /es/blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-01 13:19:27 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/31.46aa6824.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 13:19:27 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/95.1ed6b32f.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 13:19:27 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/app.c5bd2611.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 13:19:27 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/755.5a8586e9.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 13:19:27 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/runtime.725dd7e0.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 13:19:27 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/823.168b723b.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 13:19:27 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/95.22c66ae4.css HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 13:19:27 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/app.17316efd.css HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 16:34:29 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /es/blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-01 16:34:30 default[20221101t141557]  nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /tmp/google-config/nginx.conf:3
2022-11-01 16:34:33 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/95.22c66ae4.css HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 16:34:33 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/31.46aa6824.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 16:34:33 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/755.5a8586e9.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 16:34:33 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/runtime.725dd7e0.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 16:34:33 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/95.1ed6b32f.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 16:34:33 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/823.168b723b.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 16:34:33 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/app.c5bd2611.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 16:34:33 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/app.17316efd.css HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 16:34:43 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /es/blog/posts/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur-adipiscing-elit HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-01 16:34:44 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/823.168b723b.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 16:34:44 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/31.46aa6824.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 16:34:44 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/755.5a8586e9.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 16:34:44 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/app.17316efd.css HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 16:34:44 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/95.22c66ae4.css HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 16:34:44 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/runtime.725dd7e0.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 16:34:44 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/app.c5bd2611.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-01 16:34:44 default[20221101t141557]  "GET /build/95.1ed6b32f.js HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Este es mi archivo `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: php81
# threadsafe: true

handlers:
# tell appengine where our static assets live
- url: /bundles
  static_dir: web/bundles

# the symfony front controller
# - url: /.*
#  script: web/app.php

# [START env_vars]
env_variables:
  SYMFONY_ENV: prod
  DOCUMENT_ROOT: '/app/public'
# [END env_vars]
```

Y este es el entorno en el que estoy trabajando:

- Mac OSX M1 (Apple Silicon)
- PHP 8.1.12
- Symfony CLI version 5.4.17
- Composer version 2.4.4
- Google Cloud SDK 406.0.0

Si pruebo la App en local con `symfony serve` el contenido se ve perfectamente.

¿Alguna idea para resolver este problema?

Comment: ¿Es tu carpeta `build` parte de la distribución pública? No parece que la ruta sea la más "usual" en aplicaciones web, pero en todo caso, todo apunta a que dicha carpeta no es accesible desde la ruta raíz de tu "host".

Comment: fijate de configurar el bundler para que la carpeta de salida coincida con las rutas statics, puede que en local tengas uno o varios symlinks ( o que dev y prod tengan diferentes folders )

Comment: @MauricioContreras dentro de `public` tengo una carpeta `build` que es donde están los archivos .js y .css Soy nuevo en Symfony no sé si debo verificar algo más y dónde.

Comment: @aloMalbarez ¿dónde debo verificar eso? Apenas empiezo con Symfony.

Comment: el bundler/packer es encore https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/advanced-config.html#defining-multiple-webpack-configurations si ya deja los archivos en public entonces el tema puede ser la config del app engine, en el legacy hay que ponerle app_readable true https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref tal vez sea eso ( configurar los statics para que coincida con el encore y agregarle readable ) no dice mucho en el migrate https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/php-differences#migrating_your_appyaml_file

Comment: @aloMalbarez agradezco tu interés. Al parecer `application_readable` ya es obsoleto según [este post](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/php-differences#migrating_your_appyaml_file). Me enfrento a dos contextos desconocidos, `gcloud` por un lado y `symfony` por otro. Intuyo que algunas cosas han cambiado y la documentación nueva es escasa.

Comment: cla, empezaría por darle las rutas que usa encore al section handlers ( son como rewrites, fijate si symfony dejó alguna pista en un htaccess o config  ) el resto lo debería enrutar el bootstrap de symfony. lo de marcar como static assets en legacy es para que vayan a un "cdn" y que se sirvan con headers del tipo mime types, etgas, expiry, compresion (gz/brotli) etc ( todas esas cosas seo q uno mete en un htaccess  )

Comment: @aloMalbarez en la carpeta `public` hay un archivo `.htaccess` que decía de descomentar esta línea `# Options +FollowSymlinks` si hubiera problemas con los SymLinks, cosa que he hecho, guardando y desplegando de nuevo el proyecto, pero sin ningún éxito.

Comment: @aloMalbarez lo he logrado implementando un `app.yaml` parecido a [este](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/config/appref?hl=es-419), he puesto este handler `- url: /build
  static_dir: public/build` y ahora sí encuentra los `.js` y los `.css`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por si puede servir a alguno en el futuro, lo he logrado cambiando mi archivo `app.yaml` a esto:

```
runtime: php81 # Replace with php74 to use PHP 7.4

# [START cloud_tasks_app_env_vars]
env: standard
# [END cloud_tasks_app_env_vars]

handlers:
# Serve a directory as a static resource.
- url: /build
  static_dir: public/build

# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$

# Serve your app through a front controller at index.php or public/index.php.
- url: .*
  script: auto
```

Simplemente, en `handlers` tenía que declarar en el valor `url` la carpeta `/build` y en `static_dir` poner la ubicación de dicha carpeta, que en el proyecto se encuentra en `public/build`.

Este es el estilo de configuración para aplicaciones basadas en PHP 7+, según la [documentación](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/config/appref?hl=es-419).

Ahora en los logs tengo status 200:

```
2022-11-01 22:48:13 default[20221101t234515]  "GET /es HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-01 22:48:14 default[20221101t234515]  "GET /build/runtime.725dd7e0.js HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-01 22:48:14 default[20221101t234515]  "GET /build/app.17316efd.css HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-01 22:48:14 default[20221101t234515]  "GET /build/95.22c66ae4.css HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-01 22:48:14 default[20221101t234515]  "GET /build/95.1ed6b32f.js HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-01 22:48:14 default[20221101t234515]  "GET /build/app.c5bd2611.js HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-01 22:48:14 default[20221101t234515]  "GET /build/823.168b723b.js HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-01 22:48:14 default[20221101t234515]  "GET /build/31.46aa6824.js HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-01 22:48:14 default[20221101t234515]  "GET /build/755.5a8586e9.js HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-01 22:48:14 default[20221101t234515]  "GET /build/fonts/lato-bold.21b3848a.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-01 22:48:14 default[20221101t234515]  "GET /build/fonts/fa-solid-900.1551f4f6.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200
```

Y en las URL el contenido se ve correctamente.

Comment: Debieras marcar esta respuesta como aceptada.